# Meaning of solving the following Limit problem (Definition)

Tags: limits, functions, definition, limits-without-lhopital

To solve for A (assuming the limit exists):

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{60+h(x)+x+2}{-30+h(x)}=A.$$

How to evaluate this limit? Are we allowed to use the fact that, if so, then why? (definition explanation)

$$\lim_{x\to0} \:h(x)=0$$

And plug in $h(x)$ as $0$ so we get

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{60+x+2}{-30}=A.$$

And proceed to solve this with plugging $x=0$ since the function is continuous.

As we first plug in $h(x)=0$, we don't know if the whole function is continuous or any other information, so are we allowed to do it? Moreover, are we allowed (by the definition) to "solve" the limit by "plugging" the values more than once, namely: First $h(x)$ and then $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit of  a sum is the sum of the limits and limit of a ratio is the ratio of the limits provided the latter is non-zero. So, assuming that $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x)=0$, you can justify what you have done. The answer is $-\frac {62} {30}$.

Comment: If we are confronted with a much more complex limit, for the sake of simplifying the problem, are we allowed to "plug" the values many different times, for example in this case, first $x$ and then later $h(x)$? provided we know what each of their limits are.

Comment: Yes. You can plug in the limits simultaneously.

Comment: But could we plug in the limits singly not simultaneously? Just for simplifying the problem if the problem is complex.

Comment: If you plug in one limit at a  time you have keep writing $\lim $ at every step till you get the final answer. Why not do it simultaneously? Either way your answer will be the same.